# Assembler task - min and max values of the array

Tags: c++, algorithm, assembly, x86-16

I've encountered problems with assembler code. I'm a newbie to assembler, so it seems difficult for me to solve it myself.

The task is: "To find minimal and maximal elements of the array."

All I've already done is searching for maximal element. I can't find out, how to make check for the minimal element and where I should put such verification. Or, probably,  I should loop through elements second time after finding maximal element?

**Code:**

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
void main() {
   int  N = 10, i;
   clrscr();
   // on this platform, int is 16-bit
   int a[] = { 1, 4, -6, 12, -25, 10, 3, -4, 15, 7}, MAX, MIN, RESULT;

    __asm{
    mov cx, N
    lea si, a
    lodsw
    mov bx, ax
    mov dx, ax
    dec cx }
    m:
       __asm{
     lodsw
     cmp dx, ax
     jge m1
     mov dx, ax
       }
    m1:
       __asm{
       loop m
       mov MAX, dx
    }

cout << "Max = " << MAX;
//cout << "Min = " << MIN;
getch();
}
```

Comment: Is is better to compute the min in the same loop you compute the max, that is, for each element, at the time you have it in a register, test it for min at the same time you test it for max. At label `m1` seems the right place.

Comment: Thank you for help. I've understood algorithm, how to implement such verification, but unfortunately I'm not able to write code to make this code workable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's interesting to someone, here is the solution for my question(I found out it today with help of my tutor):

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
void main() {
   int  N = 10, i;
   clrscr();
   int a[] = { 1, 4, -6, 12, -25, 10, 3, -4, 15, 7}, MAX, MIN, RESULT;

    __asm{
      mov cx, N
      lea si, a
      lodsw
      mov MIN, ax
      mov MAX, ax
      dec cx
    }
    m:
     __asm{
       lodsw
       cmp MIN, ax
       jle m1
       mov MIN, ax
       jmp m2
    }
    m1:
     __asm{
       cmp MAX, ax
       jge m2
       mov MAX, ax
    }
    m2:
     __asm{
       loop m;
    }

cout << "Max = " << MAX << "\n";
cout << "Min = " << MIN;
getch();
}
```

**Algorithm**: if `cmp MIN, ax` has negative result, it means `ax` is greater, than `MIN`. So script jumps to `m1` label to compare `ax` value with `MAX`. When `cmp MIN, ax` returns positive value, scripts assigns value of `ax` register to `MIN` variable and after that jumps to the `m2` label to decrement loop counter. Algorithm of finding maximal value works similarly(label `m1`).

Answer (score 3):

What happens if you replace "jge" with "jle"?  Try it and see.

Comment: Result will be equal '-25' - the minimal value of the array.

Comment: Very good.  Now you have two loops, one to compute the min, and one to compute the max.  What would you have to do to combine them into one loop?  Hint: The loop you have is already initializing two registers (bx and dx) but currently only using one of them.